# Rail server crash on RHEL 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rhel6

I'm first timer to Ruby on Rails, trying to set it up on RHEL 6. Since the package manager had very older version of Ruby. I compiled from source with Ruby 1.9.3 and installed rails using

```
$gem install rails
```

Created a new app using

```
$rails new /path/to/newapp
```

but now when I try to run

```
$rails server
```

it crashes with given log

```
    => Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.1 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': cannot load such file -- openssl (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/session/cookie.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/cookie_store.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:140:in `const_get'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:140:in `session_store'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:268:in `block in default_middleware_stack'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:232:in `tap'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:232:in `default_middleware_stack'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:469:in `app'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:31:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /home/anurag/rubyapp/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/anurag/rubyapp/config.ru:4:in `require'
    from /home/anurag/rubyapp/config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
    from /home/anurag/rubyapp/config.ru:1:in `new'
    from /home/anurag/rubyapp/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in `wrapped_app'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:252:in `start'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I've tried to search about this error but did not find a working solution.

Apart from this I'd like to point me to some useful resource which explains best practices in Ruby on Rails.

-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem.

I went inside extracted source directory of Ruby then run these.

```
$cd /ext/openssl/
$ruby extconf.rb
$make
$make install
```

I hope other will get some help from this. :-)

Comment: doesn't work for me, after ``make`` it says "nothing to be done for all"

Answer (score 1):

Your ruby is not compiled with SSL support. Try using `rvm`:

- https://rvm.io
- https://rvm.io/packages/openssl/

Comment: I'm not using rvm.. can i compile ruby with ssl support.. something like make --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local

Comment: got the fix :) Will post fix in next 7 hours ;-)